# What does "from versions" mean in pip error message?

Tags: python, pip

On https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/2.1.1/, I copied command `pip install tensorflow-text==2.1.1` and run it.

However, pip gives error

```
> pip install tensorflow-text==2.1.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-text==2.1.1 (from versions: 2.4.0rc0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-text==2.1.1
```

Does "from versions: 2.4.0rc0" mean pip is only aware of 2.4.0rc0?

Since https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/#history lists so many versions, why is my pip only aware of one particular version?

I'm using Python 3.7.9 on Windows.

Comment: Yes, it means it only found that one version. Are you on Python 3.8 on Windows by any chance? If you look at the "Download files" section only 2.4.0rc0 seems to have that combination.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm using python 3.7

Comment: ...on what platform? Do you see a matching distribution for that on PyPI?

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK, I got it. https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-text/2.1.1/#files doesn't have Windows files. Thanks so much.